# Initialize JSF (ICEfaces) backing-bean only when page loads

Tags: spring, jsf, icefaces

I don't know how initialize a backing bean only when page loads, I am using Spring and ICEfaces.

For declare backing bean for ICEfaces I use the Spring annotation @Controller and el-resolver in faces.config.xml because I need inject service objects in the backing bean, and @ManagedBean doesn't work.

I use @PostConstructor but it is called when backing beans are created when application starts. I want to initialize my backing bean when page loads, not when backing bean is created.

doesn't work for me because it is called everytime a partial submit is doing and i need to initialize only one time

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect `@Controller` has a default scope of "singleton" and as such is initialized during application startup. You should apply `@Scope("session")` if you want to have bean initialized when it's referred to for the first time and stay in the session. `@PostConstruct` will be also called once at the appropriate time.

Comment: Thanks, I apply @Scope("request") and it works but @PostConstruct annotated method executes in partial submits (ajax calls). I want only one execution, when page loads not in ajax calls.

Comment: @AlexCuervo If you want to manage your beans with spring rather than JSF you can try something like http://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2010/02/17/port-jsf-2-0s-viewscope-to-spring-3-0/ and apply view scope to them - only available in JSF2 though.

Comment: Thanks!!!! it works perfectly!! I hope Spring introduce this scope in future releases!!